# Idris - proof on inductive step

Tags: idris

Consider the following function

```
tryMove : (diskNumber : Nat) -> (from: Peg) -> (to: Peg)-> {default Oh prf: So (from /= to)} -> Disposition diskNumber -> Maybe (Disposition diskNumber)
tryMove Z from to [] = Nothing
tryMove (S k) from to (smallestDiskPosition :: restOfTheDisposition) =
        map (smallestDiskPosition ::) (tryMove k from to restOfTheDisposition)
```

Trying to compile I get the following error:

```
When checking argument prf to Hanoi.tryMove:
        Type mismatch between
                So True (Type of Oh)
        and
                So (from /= to) (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        True
                and
                        not (Hanoi.Peg implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Eq, method == from to)
```

on the recurvise invocation of `tryMove`.
If I explicitely pass `{prf}` as in

```
tryMove : (diskNumber : Nat) -> (from: Peg) -> (to: Peg)-> {default Oh prf: So (from /= to)} -> Disposition diskNumber -> Maybe (Disposition diskNumber)
tryMove Z from to [] = Nothing
tryMove (S k) from to {prf} (smallestDiskPosition :: restOfTheDisposition) =
        map (smallestDiskPosition ::) (tryMove k from to {prf} restOfTheDisposition)
```

It compiles correctly.

Why is that that Idris can not detect automatically the proof in the inductive step, while it is able to do it in a normal invocation of the function?

EDIT:

here is a complete gist to use: https://gist.github.com/marcosh/d51479ea08e8522560713fd1e5ca9624

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You supply the default value (`Oh`) for `prf`, so Idris is trying to pass `Oh` into the recursive call.
`Oh` has type `So True` and Idris expects `prf` to be of type `So (from /= to)`, but since you don't destruct `to` and `from`, Idris cannot know the value of `from /= to`, that's why you see that error message.

You can change the signature to contain `{auto prf: So (from /= to)}` or delete the `prf` argument altogether, because you don't actually use it, you just pass it into the recursive call without any modification.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't understand one thing. What do you mean with ` since you don't destruct to and from, Idris cannot know the value of from /= to`? `from` and `to` remain the same of the initial call. If they are different in the beginning, why Idris can not uderstand that they are different after? Moreover, what do you mean by destruct `to` and `from`? How could I do that?

Comment: You pass `Oh` of type `So True` where Idris expects a value of type `So (from /= to)`, Idris will allow you to do that as long as `from /= to` and `True` are definitionally equal, or more precise in this case if `from /= to` evaluates to `True`. But to evaluate the `(/=)` function application you need to know what both arguments exactly are. Idris doesn't know that `from` and `to` are not equal. Pattern-matching is the way you propagate information. So, one extremely ugly way to help Idris would be to pattern-match on `from` and `to` -- this would generate 9 clauses (of which 3 are impossible)